# Emojis and Twitter api

Tags: php, twitter, emoji

I use twitter api from php to generate tweets. Generate the message in this way:

```
$text = utf8_encode("message content");
```

I want to add an emoji (http://www.get-emoji.com/birthday-cake/)

Try the following but it is wrong:

```
$text = utf8_encode("message ").html_entity_decode('&#x1f382;', 0, 'UTF-8').utf8_encode(" content");
```

Show the resulting content in Twitter:

"message ? content"

How can it be solved?

Comment: Have you tried copying and pasting the emoji in your string variable?

Comment: By the way: It looks like you are misusing the `utf8_encode` function. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#104906

Comment: The original text contains Spanish characters like "ñ", that's why the function is used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could do it this way:

```
$emoticon       = '&#x1f382;';
$utf8_emoticon  = html_entity_decode($emoticon, 0, 'UTF-8');
$text = utf8_encode("message ".$utf8_emoticon." content");
```